# ASP.net Display Message before long task

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, database, asynchronous

I am trying to complete something that seems like it shouldn't be too difficult but I cant seem to find a method that works.

I am calling a stored procedure on a database from an asp.net page. The procedure can take a little while depending on how much data is there.

All I want to do it display a message that says please wait while the task completes.

The problem is, I cant figure out a way to call the procedure after the page is updated with the message. No matter what I do, the page update always gets blocked by the database call.

I started by trying with a multiview. The user clicks a button, I change the view to the waiting message. I have no way from this point to wait for the page to repost and update and then call the database procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduction to the UpdateProgress Control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

In this tutorial you will use UpdateProgress controls to display the progress of partial-page updates. If a page contains UpdatePanel controls, you can also include UpdateProgress controls to keep users informed about the status of partial-page updates. You can use one UpdateProgress control to represent the progress of partial-page updates for the whole page. Alternatively, you can include an UpdateProgress control for every UpdatePanel control. Both of these patterns are shown in this tutorial.

Comment: I ended up going this route and it fits my needs fairly well. There still seems to be some issues though. First there is no way to disable the button that triggers the update without using javascript. I went ahead and used javascript and it works fine but its a little unfortunate that there isn't a built in way. The other thing is it seems to break the MultiView control. If I try to change the view in the update button it just doesn't work. I figured out a way around this but its not the nicest thing in the world.

Comment: View change should work. http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/using-multiview-control-cs.aspx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311445/using-multiview-inside-updatepanel-doesnt-update-the-view

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options, you could use the `AJAX Control Toolkit` and the UpdateProgress Control or you could use `jQuery` and call the database call using a `WebMethod` or `Web Service`.

**`AJAX Control Toolkit`**

http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdateProgressOverview.aspx

**`jQuery implementation`**

```
[WebMethod]
public void PerformDatabaseOperation() {
    // Your database code here
}
```

To perform a request to your `Web Method`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./YourPage.aspx/PerformDatabaseOperation",
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert(textStatus);
  },
  success: function(result){
     alert("success");
  }
});
```

You will have to have an `div` as a placeholder for the message:

```
<div id="LoadingMessage">
   Please wait....
</div>

$('#LoadingMessage').hide()  
.ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
})
.ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Everytime you perform a database call you would see the loading message.